# Substitute a string for multiple of 3

Tags: ruby, string

I'm printing the integers 1-100. However I want to substitute the integers that are multiples of 3 with the string `"fizz"`.

My current code is

```
if num % 3 == 0
  num.sub(/num/, "fizz");
end
```

It raises `"undefined method 'sub'"`. It is the same when I try `gsub`. Am I missing something?

Comment: It would also help if you posted all of your code

Comment: What is `num`? .......

Comment: Here are a couple of Ruby-like ways of doing that: 1) `(1..100).step(3) { |i| puts i; puts i+1; puts "fizz" }`; 2) `enum = [nil, nil, :fizzy].cycle; (1..100).each { |i| puts ((enum.next  == :fizzy) ? "fizz" : i) }`.

Answer (score 1):

sub is for strings, not integers.

Try this :

```
if num % 3 == 0
    "#{num}".sub(/#{num}/, "fizz");
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just `puts "fizz"`.  So:

```
if num % 3 == 0
  puts "fizz"
end
```

Or a more complete example:

```
(1..100).each do |num|
  if num % 3 == 0
    puts "Fizz"
  end
end
```

`sub` & `gsub` are for strings only and don't work with integers, hence your error.